# Parallel forEach search file

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have a program that contains 2 listbox, this program is bassed to search file, and then compare with a `StopWatch` the difference to use `AsyncAwait` and TPL... The first listbox does the function using  `AsyncAwait` (I don't know if it's the better way to do but it works, see my code below)

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Visual Studio Projectes\Hash\AsyncAwait\Carpetes"))
    {    
        foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(d))
        {
            stopWatch.Start();
            listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            await Task.Delay(1);
            btIniciar1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    btIniciar1.Enabled = true;
    stopWatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    textBox1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff") + (" minuts");
}
```

And then in my second listbox is where I'm stuck, I don't know how to implement the `Parallel.ForEach` to act like `async`,  what's the better way to do this? I can't find the way to use TPL in this case to do the same as my first listbox, could you help me please?

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF? Also it is not exactly clear what you are trying to do, if you are just trying to add a list of files to `listBox1` If so, your parallel solution will be slower because you can only have one thread add items at a time and everyone will have to wait its turn. If you are doing something else ForEach might work better but you need to show us what your ForEach will really do.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach would be bad for this, as only the UI thread can update the UI, so you would have to change back to this thread to actually add the file to the list. Better to return an array of strings (e.g. filenames) from a function if you really must try this kind of experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've solved this issue doing this :

```
 DirectoryInfo nodeDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\files");
 Parallel.ForEach(nodeDir.GetDirectories(), async dir =>
 {
    foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(dir.FullName))
    {
       Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbxParallel.Items.Add(s); }));
       contador++;
      await Task.Delay(1);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no point in using `async` in your example code, since it's not actually doing anything asynchronously. If you want to wrap the synchronous code in a background thread, use `Task.Run`.

Regarding `Parallel.ForEach`, you can treat it asynchronously by wrapping it in `Task.Run`: `await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach(...));`

Note that parallel/background threads cannot directly access UI elements. You can use `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` if you want to update the UI from a background/threadpool thread.

**Update:**

The serial code would look like:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(update =>
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    btIniciar1.Enabled = false;
  });
  var ts = await Task.Run(() =>
  {
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Visual Studio Projectes\Hash\AsyncAwait\Carpetes"))
    {
      foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(d))
      {
        stopWatch.Start();
        progress.Report(s);
      }
    }
    stopWatch.Stop();
    return stopWatch.Elapsed;
  });
  btIniciar1.Enabled = true;
  textBox1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff") + (" minuts");
}
```

The parallel code would look like:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(update =>
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
    btIniciar1.Enabled = false;
  });
  var ts = await Task.Run(() => Parallel.ForEach( ...
  ));
  btIniciar1.Enabled = true;
  textBox1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ff") + (" minuts");
}
```